# Sequelize - query foreign key fields with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have this NotificationApp model defined under server/models:

```
const DataTypes = withDateNoTz(SequelizeDataTypes);

const NotificationApp = sequelize.define('NotificationApp', {
    Id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    CreatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE_NO_TZ,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    CreatedById: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        onDelete: 'set null',
        references: {
            model: 'User',
            key: 'Id',
        },
    },
    TaskId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        onDelete: 'cascade',
        allowNull: true,
        references: {
            model: 'Task',
            key: 'Id',
        },
    },
    CommentId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        onDelete: 'cascade',
        allowNull: true,
        references: {
            model: 'Comment',
            key: 'Id',
        },
    },
    GoalId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        onDelete: 'cascade',
        allowNull: true,
        references: {
            model: 'Goal',
            key: 'Id',
        },
    },
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
});

NotificationApp.associate = (models) => {
    NotificationApp.belongsTo(models.User, { as: 'CreatedBy' });
    NotificationApp.belongsTo(models.Task);
    NotificationApp.belongsTo(models.Comment);
    NotificationApp.belongsTo(models.Goal);
};

return NotificationApp;
```

I want to check if my `req.body.ProjectId`, is equal to the `ProjectId` field of my Task, Comment or Goal models. This is my current query:

```
const notificationApp = await db.NotificationApp.findAll({
    // TODO: WHERE Task.ProjectId = req.body.ProjectId OR
    // Comment.ProjectId = req.body.ProjectId OR
    // Goal.ProjectId = req.body.ProjectId
    where: {
        // [Op.or]: [
        //     { }
        // ],
    },
    offset: body.PagingParameter.Skip,
    limit: body.PagingParameter.Take,
    include: [
        {
            model: await db.User,
            attributes: { exclude: hideAttributes },
            as: 'CreatedBy',
            include: { model: await db.UserPic },
        },
        {
            model: await db.Comment,
        },
        {
            model: await db.Task,
        },
        {
            model: await db.Goal,
        },
    ],
    order: [['CreatedAt', 'DESC']],
});
```

I can use `[Op.or]` for this but I don't know how to access the fields of my associations. How do I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: I think your where clauses are actually going to go inside of your includes, based on how I am reading this. Check out this section of the Sequelize docs. https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#eager-loading-filtered-at-the-associated-model-level

Comment: I also think you're going to want to remove all of those "await"s on the models inside of the include array.